# Can't set up printer

Tags: windows-xp, printing

I'm trying to set up an HP OFficejet Pro 8500 A909a on my Windows XP machine over the network.

I know the IP address of the printer but it's unclear to me how to set it up based on that. I have no idea how to troubleshoot this problem.

I've tried installing the drivers but when I do that it tells me the printer is on a different gateway from my workstation, which is not true.

Also, other people in the office are able to connect to this printer just fine, although the driver apparently didn't work for them, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If it's a Shared Printer**

Go to Start
Run
Type \\(IP Address Here)
Find the printer
Right Click
Click Connect.

**If it's a network printer you would do the following:**

Go to Start
Printers and Faxes
Right click in the blank space in the right pane -> New Printer
Next
Local Printer Attached to this computer
Uncheck "Automaticly..."
Next
Create New Port
Select Standard TCP/IP Port
Next
Printer Name or IP Address: This is the IP Address
Name the port(whatever you want)
Next
Click "Have Disk"
Browse to where you unzipped the driver. and pick the ini file
Next
Name the printer
Next
Decide if you want a test page
Next
Finish